# AngularJS recursive templates using tables

Tags: angularjs, recursion

I am trying to work out how to do recursion using table tags with angularjs. I have the following data structure

```
$scope.report = [{
  'Name': 'Moo',
  'Value': 'MooV',
  'Children': [{
    'Name': 'Moo2',
    'Value': 'Moo2V',
    'Children': [{
      'Name': 'Moo3',
      'Value': 'Moo3V'
    }]
  }]
}];
```

The recursion can have no limit. I am looking to put in a simple table with the format

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Moo</td>
    <td>MooV</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moo2</td>
    <td>Moo2V</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moo3</td>
    <td>Moo3v</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

but I am unable to get it working just right. This will allow me to do certain things to the sections while looking flat to the user. Currently I have the code

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="rloop">
    <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Value}}</td>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in data.Children" ng-include src="'rloop'"></tr>
  </script>

  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="data in report" ng-include="'rloop'"></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

but this is not going to work due to in repeating it creates a tr tag within a tr tag. I have tried various different methods of moving the repeat to tbody etc etc but I can't seems to get it working due to the restrictions of tables in HTML. Example,  is not allowed within tr.

JSFiddle showing issue here: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hubnerd/h860924g/)

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this is not going to work within the table. Maybe it would be better to recursively convert the data to an array of Name/Value pairs, then use those in the normal way?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function includeChildren([first, ...rest]) {
    if (!first) return [];
  
    const {Name, Value, Children = []} = first;
  
    return [{Name, Value}, ...includeChildren(Children), ...includeChildren(rest)];
}

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.report = [{
      'Name': 'Moo',
      'Value': 'MooV',
      'Children': [{
        'Name': 'Moo2',
        'Value': 'Moo2V',
        'Children': [{
          'Name': 'Moo3',
          'Value': 'Moo3V'
        }]
      }]
    }];
    
  $scope.reportTable = includeChildren($scope.report);
  // $scope.reportTable now contains: 
  // [{Name: 'Moo', Value: 'MooV'}, {Name: 'Moo2', Value: 'Moo2V'}, {Name: 'Moo3', Value: 'Moo3V'}]
});
```

Now you can use a more unsurprising template:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in reportTable">
      <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.Value}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/k6rf9g1p/1/